# How to properly cast this class for OCMockito?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ocmockito

I'm using `OCMockito` to mock some objects in my tests.

When I use `verify` I receive an error from Xcode:

> Multiple methods named '.....' found with mismatched result, parameter type or attributes

In the readme of the project i found this note:

> (If Xcode complains about multiple methods with the same name, cast verify to the mocked class.)

This is my original implementation:

```
__strong Class mockAdjustClass = mockClass([Adjust class]);
[verify(mockAdjustClass) trackEvent:hasProperty(@"callbackParameters", hasEntry(@"duration", isNot(@"0")))];
```

I tried to cast in different ways but i cannot get rid of the error, for example:

```
[verify(([Adjust class])mockAdjustClass) trackEvent:hasProperty(@"callbackParameters", hasEntry(@"duration", isNot(@"0")))];

[([Adjust class])verify(mockAdjustClass) trackEvent:hasProperty(@"callbackParameters", hasEntry(@"duration", isNot(@"0")))];
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution and was very easy :(

```
[(Adjust *)verify(mockAdjustClass) trackEvent:hasProperty(@"callbackParameters", hasEntry(@"duration", isNot(@"0")))];
```